# Wordpress WooCommerce ChargeLogic Testing Checkout Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a client wanting to use Wordpress WooCommerce with ChargeLogic as its payment processor.  I installed the plugins and put in the test credentials for the client's account.  Inventory and products and some settings were pulled in and everything seems to be working perfectly until I try to do a test checkout. (Test mode is turned on.)  Once I enter account and credit card info, I get the message *"There is a problem with your credentials. Please contact customer service."*

I have tried test credit card numbers from Authorize.net who ChargeLogic lists as a supported payment processor, but got the error. I have even tried a Stripe test card and a live gift card.  All get the same error. I could not find any test credit card info specifically for ChargeLogic.

Does anyone know if the WooCommerce ChargeLogic plugin allows test checkouts, or if you have to set up another payment processor such as an Authorize.net payment option to get it to work? Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChargeLogic got back with me. Someone entered the wrong application ID when they filled out their credentials.

The application ID was set to:
WORDPRESS

And it needed to be set to:
WOOCOMMERCE